# COUNTIFS with criteria range in both column and row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please refer sample workbook here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EBHj41vQcfS8ifo_Eknpw8rNxh6r06D-KAZOG5jr5Mo/edit#gid=891738929

I have a table summarizing count of A, M, T occurence for each student by Subject and Step.

However, I only managed to get the count for each A, M, T by student but not specific to subject and step by using this formula

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(Maths!$F$3:$Q$64,0,MATCH($B6,Maths!$F$2:$Q$2,0)),"A")
```

I guess I need to put in one more countif statement but it does not work because my argument exceed the syntax? Can you guys please advise me how to include one more countif statement in above formula?

Eventually I expect to have the count for A, M, T for **each subject** and **step** for **each student**.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION and explain in words what the expected result should be, instead of posting a formula that does not deliver it. Post a comment AFTER YOU HAVE UPDATED YOUR QUESTION. Please follow these instructions.

Comment: Please edit the question to be understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve (as far as I understand it) cannot be done with a Countifs function. You need Sumproduct for that.

Enter this formula into cell C6, then copy across and down.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Maths!$E$2:$Q$64=C$5)*(Maths!$E$2:$E$64=C$4)*(Maths!$E$2:$Q$2=$B6))
```

The result in cell E6, for example, will be 2, because Student A has 2 "T" values for "Maths Step 1" in the Maths sheet.

[image]

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly and actually very easy! Thanks. Appreciate it a lot!